# How can I embed a conditional comment for IE with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, innerhtml, conditional-comments

Ok so I want to conditionally add this line of code;

```
<!--[if ! IE]> <embed src="logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /> <![endif]-->
```

Using:

```
document.getElementById("logo") .innerHTML='...';
```

In a `if()/else()` statement and it don't write it!
If i get rid of the selective comment ( `<!--[if ! IE]><![endif]-->`) and only put the SVG ( `<embed src="logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />` ) it work! what should I do?

I found a way around but i think in the Android browser the thing will pop up twice.

```
here's what I've done ( and its Validated stuff!);

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META CHARSET="UTF-8">
<title>SVG Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
onload=function()
    {

        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {

        document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML='<img src="fin_palais.png"/>';

        }


    }
//]]>

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="logo">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <img src="fin_palais.png"/>
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->

            <embed src="fin_palais.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />

        <!--<![endif]-->

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for detecting not IE is broken.

**Microsoft recommended way - results in bad markup**

```
<![if !IE]>
 <p>This is shown in downlevel browsers, but is invalid HTML!</p>
<![endif]>
```

**This way shows works too and is valid markup**

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
  <p>This is shown in downlevel browsers.</p>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

That said, @jfriend00's comment is good.

Your way begins an `html comment` which is never closed, and thus doesn't process correctly.  `html comments` are opened with the first `--` and closed with the second.  They don't close with the `>` like regular elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to not put it in the innerHTML, but use the condition to control whether it goes in the innerHTML or not like this:

```
var str = '...';    // whatever your other HTML is
<!--[if ! IE]>
str += '<embed src="logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />';
<![endif]-->
```

If you show us the whole problem you're trying to solve, there are probably ways to do this without browser conditionals.

Comment: I think i actualy found a way around! but what i try to reatch is a way to be shure an SVG will be displayed any where the browser support it and else where its a png that pop's up instead, including IE and Android browser